# Show different content in static block based on product type

Tags: product, custom, static-block

I have created a custom tab. 
I want to show different content in this custom tab.

If product type is `simple`
show simple product

If product type is `virtual`
show virtual product

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please post some code with your question of what you have done so far to add the tab to make it easier for us to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

If it is on a productpage, you can add it in a local.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple> or <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

or you could

```
$product = $this->getProduct() ? $this->getProduct() : Mage::registry('current_product');

if ($product->getTypeId() === 'simple') {
    // do something
} elseif ($product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mkgarg,You can don this by layout handler.When a product page is rendered the magento create a dynamic  handler using below  code:`$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId());`

So ,on `simple product  page`,magento is called layout handler `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple`

and   on `virtual  product`  page,magento is called layout handler `PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual`.

In default  [catalog.xm](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml)l file you can see  lot work depends on product type:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    .....
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
       ......      </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
.....
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```